# using dasBaum: page is reloaded and entry is not made in tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using [dasBaum](https://github.com/godmodelabs/dasBaum) plug-in, the problem is, when i click on any of the 2 buttons to add the items the page is been reloaded and the item is not added to the tree.

What i have done in my page:i have created some tabs and 3rd tab i placed a div inside which the tree(that div which contains the items)  is there.

U can see the dasBaum.js in the link i have given.

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/jquery.multiselect2side.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/TableTools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/tab-menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/excellentexport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/xlReader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/eRoster.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/utils.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/linq.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/Require.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/dasBaum.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jsPath; ?>js/json2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 
</head>



 <!-- CREATED TABS DIV HERE, IN THIRD DIV I HAVE PUT "CONTAINER" DIV -->
 <body>
 ------------------
 ------------------
 <div id="container">
        <center class="headline">
            <button id="btFolder">New Folder</button>
            <button id="btEntry">New Entry</button>
        </center>

        <div id="tree">
        </div>
        <div style="color:white">
            <div class="headline">Features</div>
            Drag&amp;Drop to reorder items<br/>
            Doubleclick to rename
            <div class="headline">Hotkeys</div>
            <strong>Space:</strong> Toggle Item<br/>
            <strong>Up/Down:</strong> Move Cursor<br/>
            <strong>Enter:</strong> Select<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
   --------------
   --------------

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                $('#tree').dasBaum('handleKey',e);
            })
            $('#btFolder').click(function() {
                $('#tree').dasBaum('addItem',{label:'New Entry',items:[]})
            });
            $('#btEntry').click(function() {
                $('#tree').dasBaum('addItem',{label:'New Entry'});
            });
            console.log("bfore dasBaum");
            debugger;
            $('#tree').dasBaum({
                sort: true,
                foldersOnTop: true,
                items: [
                    {

                        label:'D',
                        items: [{label:'E'}]

                    },
                    {label:'A'},
                    {label:'B'},
                    {label:'C'},
                ]
            });debugger;
        });
    </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

plz go to the link for dasBaum.js or .css files.
I am using jquery-ui-1.11.2.js in my project, this may make difference.

Comment: Code to reproduce..? online demo..? Something that can help those trying to help you, other than problem description?

Comment: i have given the link in which the demo of the plug-in is there, if u want what i tried, then it's too large i have to shorten the code then only i can post otherwise no body will read it.i'll try.

Comment: That's correct http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: plz have a look i have added some code which a have done other files are plug-ins u can find it in the link. hope this will help. @TJ